# Change Title of Button in angularjs data grid

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a data table grid where i would like to change the title of the arrows buttons based on the selection made.

For Example : By default the data in the columns is sorted by descending order so the title of the arrow button  should display  :Ascending sorting Indicator  and when the column is sorted descending then the arrows title should display ascending.

```
 <thead>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="column in columns" class="text-center sortable"
                ng-class="{'sort-asc': grdProjects.isSortBy(column.field, 'asc'),'sort-desc': grdProjects.isSortBy(column.field, 'desc')}"
                ng-click="grdProjects.sorting(column.field, grdProjects.isSortBy(column.field, 'asc') ? 'desc' : 'asc')"
                ng-style="{'width':column.width}">

                <button  class="border_less_button sort-indicator" title="{{column.title}} blah Sorting Indicator" ng-if="column.title">
                    {{column.title}}
                </button>
            </th>
        </tr>
</thead>
```

Comment: Can someone answer this question please.

Comment: Try removing ng-if="column.title" from botton.

Comment: I removed,but it has nothing to do with it.